# Which monster did Darth Bane fight when he landed on the moon Dxun?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In [*Darth Bane: Rule of Two*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Bane:_Rule_of_Two) Darth Bane fights a beast in Dxun’s forest:

> With the beast no longer concealed by Dxun’s forest, Bane got his first good look at the thing that had nearly killed him. It studied
>   him with luminous green eyes that were definitely feline, though its
>   fur was a metallic gray coat flecked with tiny bronze plates that
>   shimmered as the muscles moved beneath the skin. It stood a meter and
>   a half at the shoulder, easily weighing three hundred kilograms. It
>   had four thick, muscular legs that ended in razor-sharp retractable
>   claws. But the feature that drew Bane’s immediate attention was the
>   serpentine twin tails, each tipped with a deadly barb that dripped
>   glowing green venom.

Although it's not specifically named I want to know which monster he fought. Was it a Drexl beast or a Srkeev or something else?

Comment: please try to reserve the [tag:sith] tag for question that are specifically about the Sith Order, and not for questions that just happen to be about an individual Sith.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield This *is* about the history of the Sith, so the tag is relevant.

Comment: No, it's about identifying a creature a Sith lord happened to fight. If it had been Luke Skywalker instead of Darth Bane who fought this monster it would be the same answer.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield If it was about a monster Luke Skywalker had fought, it would have been tagged luke-skywalker instead. It definitely needs the star-wars-legends tag, though...

Comment: Don't even get me started on character-specific tags. Those are evil. Also, totally missed my point there. :)

Comment: @MikeEdenfield I don't like character tags, either, but the community has decided that tags for major characters (like Luke) are acceptable (incidentally, [you wrote the guidelines](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6839/when-should-character-tags-be-created-recreated)). This is a questionable case so I'll agree to leave the tag off. I'm not adding the tag to every question that mentions the Sith in passing, but there are quite a few questions that should obviously have the tag. (btw, I'm not getting notifications -- please include my username in your comments.)

Answer (score 7):

Part of the description in the passage(s) at the end of the quoted excerpt gives us the key.

> But the feature that drew Bane's immediate attention was the serpentine twin tails, each tipped with a deadly barb that dripped glowing green venom.

**Gharzr**. From [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gharzr):

> They were notable for their twin stinging tails and stealthy hunting tactics.

There's nothing about green eyes in the description but there is an image in the article:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description of the beasts (notably the feline features and long claws) he was attacked by a [maalraa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Maalraas), one of several predatory species native to Dxun.

> *Maalraas or Nighthunters were a non-sentient species of predatory quadrupeds. Nighthunters hunted in packs, using long claws and
>   powerful fanged jaws to disable their victims. Using the Force to
>   cloak themselves, making themselves nearly indistinguishable from the
>   darkest shadows; only well-trained Jedi or Sith could recognize their
>   silhouettes.*

[image: maalraa]

Comment: no before that "Bane had sensed the beast at the last possible instant, his Force awareness giving him a precognitive warning that allowed him to duck clear of the lethal claws. " " Bane got his first good look at the thing that had nearly killed him. It studied him with luminous green eyes that were definitely feline,"

Comment: @Richard This doesn't have the twin tails.